# Issue with TextDetectorCNN_create

Tags: opencv, ocr

I am running opencv 4.1.0 Windows 10 64 bit with python 3.7.

My code is:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:/projects/kort/Hjerter/IMG_2383.jpg')

det = cv2.text.TextDetectorCNN_create("c:/projects/Caffe/textbox.prototxt", "c:/projects/Caffe/TextBoxes_icdar13.caffemodel")

rects, probs = det.detect(img)
```

Here is the error I get (below). Any hints?

```
rects, probs = det.detect(img)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\text\src\text_detectorCNN.cpp:66: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void cdecl cv::text::TextDetectorCNNImpl::detect(const class cv::InputArray &,class std::vector > &,class std::vector &)'
>   (expected: 'inputImage.channels() == inputChannelCount_'), where
>   'inputImage_.channels()' is 1
>   must be equal to
>   'inputChannelCount_' is 3

Comment: The error message is pretty clear! [cv::text::TextDetectorCNN::detect](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d1/d66/classcv_1_1text_1_1TextDetectorCNN.html#ac935f5cbfc3305784626d2fa4e49bb25) expects a 3-channel image, but you most likely provided a 1-channel image. Is `IMG_2383.jpg` a grayscale image? Do you do any other pre-processing, which you haven't shown here?

Comment: Thanks HansHirse, My image is a colour image, but I will try to expand the image to 3 channels. Soren.